# How can I export my translation changes?

Tags: 7, i18n-l10n

I am using Core Module Locale in Drupal 7. What is the easiest way to export just my language changes? How do I find out which strings have been modified?

Comment: That seems really hard. At first look, I didn't found any hook to implements. So... what is your need exactly ? Why do you want export just changed translations ? Do you need a one shoot process or something industrialized ?

Comment: Thank you for your reply, Nikolas.

Basically I just want import my language modifications to a new Drupal installations. Currently I am using a plain text file to record all changes which is kind of inconvenient. Any advice? Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With locale module, you have an export tab here : admin/config/regional/translate/export. Or through the menu : Configuration > Regional and language > Export.

On a fresh installation, active the locale module and go to the import tab : admin/config/regional/translate/import. Or through the menu : Configuration > Regional and language > Import.

Comment: Yeah, this is exactly I was looking for. Thank you! The only downside is that the export option saves ALL strings including Drupal core translations. There’s no option to export strings that have been overwritten. So, I will loose all my changes when I use Drupal localization updates. Of course I can set the l10n_update Import behaviour to „Don't overwrite existing translations.“ but than I will not benefit from new translation string updates. I hope this makes sense.